# Overlaying two audio files with ffmpeg in C#

Tags: c#, .net, audio, ffmpeg

I'm learining [NReco](http://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx) wrapper for ffmpeg, and trying to implement "damage" filter to audio like in this [video](https://vimeo.com/20608724).
I have an audio file, and a "filter", then they should be merged to the finalised 3rd audio file.
I think that I should use ffmpeg parameters in this way:

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp3 -i filter.mp3 -filter_complex amerge -ac 2 -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 output.mp3
```

And second part is how to chage volume of the "filter" and loop it throught main audio file duration before merging.
I'm not sure if ffmpeg has it's own filter-like method, so any proposals are welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question by this way

to merge the track with filters:

```
string command = "-y -i TRACK.mp3 -i FILTER.mp3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=2 MIX.mp3";
        var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
        ffMpeg.Invoke(command);
```

to changing the volume of filter:

```
string command = "-y -i FILTER.mp3 -af "volume=xx.xxxx" NEWFILTER.mp3"
        var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
        ffMpeg.Invoke(command);
```